# Spring annotations validation using @BindingResult

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jsp

I am developing a simple Spring MVC app. 
I have a `controller` called `CustomerController` and `customer-form.jsp` for showing my `form` and `customer-confirmation.jsp` for showing the result and `Customer` for form validation.

> I am trying to have validation for `lastname` field which doesn't let the user leave it empty. In controller I am using BindingResult to take control over user input so the form shouldn't let the user leave the  lastname empty but unfortunately its doses. I have no idea what is wrong.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/customer")
public class CustomerController {
    @RequestMapping("/showForm")
    public String showForm(Model theModel){
        theModel.addAttribute("customer",new Customer());
        return "customer-form";

    }
@RequestMapping("/processForm")
    public String processForm(
            @Valid @ModelAttribute("customer") Customer theCustomer,
            BindingResult theBindingResult

){
        if(theBindingResult.hasErrors()){
            return "customer-form";
        }
        else{
        return"customer-confirmation";
}
    }
}
```

```
public class Customer {
    private String firstName;
    @NotNull(message = "is requiard")
    @Size(min = 1)
    private String lastName;


    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
}
```

customer-form.jsp

```
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>

<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>costomer form</title>
    <style>
        .error{color: red}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<form:form action="processForm"  modelAttribute="customer">
    FirstName: <form:input path="firstName"/>
    <br/><br/>
    LastName(*): <form:input path="lastName"/>
    <form:errors path="lastName" cssClass="error"/>
    <br/><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="submit">


</form:form>
</body>
</html>
```

customer-confirmation.jsp

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
${customer.firstName}
<br/><br/>
${customer.lastName}
hello costomet
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: what is the error ?

Comment: there is no actual error. I used spring validation annotation for prevent user to leave lastname empty but it dosent work. you can leave it without any input

Comment: it supposed to show error messages if user dosen't enter the lastname but unfortunately it doesn't work

Comment: your code is working perfectly. how are you testing it ?

Comment: in customer-form.jsp i leave the lastname empty it shouldn't let me see customer-confirmation.jsp and show me error message for validation but it doesn't.it's like i have no validation for lastname

Comment: can you attach screenshot after it moves to customer-confirmation.jsp ?